# Sufficient statistics of a bernoulli random vector of size K

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Imagine a K-dimensional random variable (RV) **X** following the Bernoulli distribution. According to [this article](https://pages.stat.wisc.edu/%7Esding/paper/mvb.pdf), such an RV needs $2^K-1$ parameters (probabilities) to be fully determined.

1. Does it mean a full description of **X** requires moments above 2 (mean and variance)?
2. How can one, in practice, avoid such an exponential scaling in problems involving multivariate Bernoullis?

Comment: A multivariate Bernoulli distribution seems to be *any* distribution on the $2^K$ possible outcomes, subject only to the usual requirement that the probabilities are non-negative and sum to $1$ (which is why the $2^K$th parameter is determined by the others).  So no, you cannot avoid this exponential scaling without making further restrictions

Comment: Thanks, @Henry. I'll mark it as the answer if you post it as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From comments:*

A multivariate Bernoulli distribution seems to be any distribution on the $2^K$ possible outcomes, subject only to the usual requirement that the probabilities are non-negative and sum to $1$ (which is why the $2^K$th parameter is determined by the others).

So no, you cannot avoid this exponential scaling without making further restrictions